# Parse a redirect page with php Simple HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, php, regex, simple-html-dom

I am dynamically generating a url to be parsed with PHP Simple HTML DOM but that page directs to another dynamically greated URL using Javascript, below is the script that redirects it

```js
<script>window.addEventListener('load', function() { window.location.replace('http://thatsthem.com/search/417-272-0471/7312f62d') });</script>
```

So I need a way for the PHP to follow the redirect through to `http://thatsthem.com/search/417-272-0471/7312f62d` and then parse that page. But all it  does is just load that javascript and then executes it and opens the new page.

Or if I can some how extract the URL from the javascript with regex or something and then have my PHP just parse that url, that would work also. But I can't figure out how to get that url out of the script with php.

I feel like I'm in Inception right now

Thanks in advance!

Here my script is

```
<body>

<form method="post" id="primarysearchfomr">
<input name="number" type="text" value=""/>
<input type="submit" id="searchbutton"/>

</form>

<h1 id="searchform">Search Form</h1>


 <?php
  $searchterm= $_POST["number"];

 $count = null;
  $returnValue = str_replace(array("(",")","-"," "), '', $searchterm,    $count);




   include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
   $target_url = "http://thatsthem.com/searching?ff=true&q0=" . $returnValue;


   $html = new simple_html_dom();
   $html->load_file($target_url);
    foreach($html->find('script',2) as $link)
   {

    echo $link;
    }
```

Comment: I am confused. If, as you say, your script loads and executes that javascript based redirection and comes out at the target place (however you did that), then what is your question? Isn't that _exactly_ what you want?

Comment: where/how are you dynamically generating this url? If you're building that entire `<script>...</script>` block, presumably you'd have the url somewhere separate already anyways.

Comment: No, i want it to parse that redirect page and then echo the elements parsed not just load that page

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand what you have: _what_ "loads" that page?

Comment: Marc B, I am generating the first url based on form in put and joining it with the constant part of the URL but then that page redirects to another url that it creates somehow and that is the URL that I need to parse not the one I am creating

Comment: Sorry, please add additional information to the question above and delete this comment. There is an `edit` button below your question... The code is not really readable here in a comment.

Comment: @arkascha  I am using simple HTML DOM php to parse(crawl a page)  but the page it is suppose to crawl redirects to another page using javascript. So I need my script to go on to that next page and crawl it and then echo certain elements on the first page (the page I have all my PHP on) but it wont crawl that page it only crawl the the first URL I created and and then a second later it will execute the just simply open a browser window of the next url instead of crawling it and eching elements

Comment: There is no robust solution for this by parsing the url from the javascript, since that javascript obviously can change every minute. The only reliable approach I can see would be to use a headless but js enabled browser on the server side to normally load the target and see where it comes out. That would exactly mimic a normal browsers behavior.

Comment: @arkascha I'm not sure what you mean by "headless"? and the javascript I would like to parse will remain the same, I just I need to use Regex to pull the url out of the javascript but make sure the script isn't loaded on to the page and ran.

Comment: Well, ok, if you say it is static, then indeed you can use a regular expression to extract the URL. There are endless examples for regular expressions extracting URLs. Do you have any specific question about that? Something primitive would be `"/window\.location\.replace\('([^']+)'\)/"`... A hint: try an online regex tool to try around yourself.

Comment: @arkascha Okay, I'll start tooling around with regex, I've never used it before but it is sounding like the way to go, thanks for your help!

Comment: Google for "online regex tool", take the first hit, enter the expression and the js code (remove the enclosing `"` and the `/` from the regex) and you will see: it matches. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to pull that url out with regex? That should look something like:

```
$script = "<script>window.addEventListener('load', function() { window.location.replace('http://thatsthem.com/search/417-272-0471/7312f62d') });</script>";

if(preg_match("/'(http.*?)'/", $script, $m)){
  $url = $m[1];
  die($url);
}
```